# I think my destructor is causing an error to occur. Can you help me figure out why?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

**The problem is in my assignment operator, I've forgotten to deallocate and reallocate memory for my pointer in my string class. I must have accidentally treated it like a copy constructor; This has been a great lesson in why memory management is very important. Thanks everyone for your help.**

ive implemented my own string class and this seems to be the last function on the call stack before it breaks.

```
String::~String(){
    delete [] rep;
    len=0;
}
```

Can someone help me understand what the problem is?

Here is the function which calls it

```
template <class T> 
void SList<T>::RemoveAfter(typename SList<T>::Iterator i){        
    assert(i.nodePointer !=0 && i.nodePointer->next!=0);
    Node *save = i.nodePointer -> next;
    i.nodePointer->next = i.nodePointer->next->next;
    delete save;

}
```

If there is any more info you need to help me figure out why this occurs let me know.

By the way, if I use a type int, I dont have this problem, so I know the issue has to be with my string class...right?

More info as requested:

```
struct Node{ // Node: Stores the next Node and the data.
    T data;
    Node *next;
    Node() {next =0;}
    Node(const T& a, Node *p = 0){data=a;next=p;}

};
```

the error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Algorithms.exe.
>   This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Algorithms.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>   This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Algorithms.exe has focus.
>   The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Example functionality that breaks:

```
    String item1("Example"), item2("Example");
    SList<String> list1;        
    list1.AddFirst(item2);
    list1.AddFirst(item1);
    list1.AddLast("List Class");
    list1.AddLast("Functionality");

    SList<String>::Iterator i1;

    i1 = list1.Begin();     
    i1++;
    i1++;
    list1.RemoveAfter(i1);
```

Example that works

```
    SList<int> list1;       
    list1.AddFirst(1);
    list1.AddFirst(2);
    list1.AddLast(3);
    list1.AddLast(4);

    SList<int>::Iterator i1;

    i1 = list1.Begin();     
    i1++;
    i1++;
    list1.RemoveAfter(i1);


    system("pause");
```

More information:

```
//Default Constructor
String::String(){
rep = new char[1];
rep[0] = '\0';
len = 0;
}  

//Constructor - Converts char* to String object
String::String(const char *s){
len=0;
const char *temp = s;
while(*temp){
    ++len;
    ++temp;
}//Sets len of rep to the length of s
rep = new char[len + 1];
for(int i=0; i<=len; ++i)
    rep[i]=s[i];
}

//Copy Constructor
String::String(const String &obj){
len=0;
char *temp = obj.rep;

while (*temp){
    ++len;
    ++temp;
}//Sets len of rep to length of obj.rep
rep = new char[len + 1];
for (int i = 0; i<=len; ++i)
    rep[i] = obj.rep[i];
}

//Assignment operator
const String& String::operator=(const String &rhs){
if (this != &rhs){
    len=0;
    char *temp = rhs.rep;
    while(*temp){
        ++len;
        ++temp;
    }//Sets len of this to length of rhs.rep
    for(int i = 0; i<=len;++i)
        rep[i]=rhs.rep[i];
}
return *this;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid pasting tabs into the code blocks as they can mess up the formatting. I've fixed this particular case for you.

Comment: You'll need to provide at least the declaration of your `Node` class, as your code don't show any occurence of `String` usage.

Comment: It may help to see what the template class does with `T` values (e.g. does it store any as fields or call methods on them); the part of it that you showed isn't using `T` for anything special.  Also note, there is no point in a simple assignment like `len=0;` in a destructor.  My *guess* from what you've shown is that your `String` might violate the "Rule of three" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) but I'd need to see more to know for sure.

Comment: "If you use a type int" where? Please post a self-contained example of what goes wrong and what avoids the problem.

Comment: I'd like to see your String's constructors (all of them) and assignment operators. In addition to your class's definition, of course

Comment: @user1 I updated with the error

Comment: @rotoglup I provided the information you requested

Comment: @KevinGrant I also updated with more information that could help

Comment: @Potatoswatter I gave self contained examples

Comment: @YePhlck let me know if my edits help you

Comment: Just give your intelligence a chance before rushing to StackOverflow next time.

Comment: @Desmond Hume I will: I have a midterm in an hour and in case I wanted to test out any functions im asked to write, I wanted to make sure all my classes were working. However, I did not want to waste time looking for the error as that time could be spent applying myself and studying harder. You can try to understand that the stress of an exam that is worth 40% of your grade can sometimes derail your normal, patient debugging mindset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your assignment operator you are potentially writing outside the bounds of the allocated area pointed to by `char* rep`, which will probably corrupt the stack (ie. cause *undefined-behavior*).

When you later try to deallocate this segment of memory a corrupt stack might cause things to go banans, and it's a very plausible this is the reason for the error message you are receiving when running your application.

As stated by the message itself *"this may be due to a **corruption of the heap**"*.

---

#### How do I fix my problem?

Inside your assignment operator you will need to do three things:

1. deallocate the previous allocated memory in *this* (unless *this->len*  and *rhs.len* have the same value, if so; skip step *2.* as well)
2. allocate the same amount of memory as *rhs* has for *rhs.rep* (ie. *rhs.len* bytes)
3. update *this->len* to represent the length of the new content
4. copy the bytes stored in the memory pointed to by *rhs.rep* to the memory segment pointed to by *this->rep*.

Currently you are only doing step 3 & 4.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing this out. I had copied this class straight from my professor and I accidentally 2 lines...one that deleted the current rep, and the one that created a new rep. Big woops!! Thank you. I learned a lot from this.

Comment: @DeadMG great advice for the future but for now the value gained by writing and maintaining these classes is that I'm hopefully well prepared for my midterm. Even if I am not, stack-overflow was able to teach me something today. I'm not the best debugger and im still learning the fundamental programming concepts, I have been studying near all week now its crunch time..